# Joining Tables in sql Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables in oracle DB as shown below:

Training_Calendar_hdr

```
-----------------------------
Training_Id     Training_Name
-----------------------------
T1               Physics
T2               Chemistry
T3               Maths
```

Training_Employee_mapping

```
---------------------------
Training_Id   Employee_Id
---------------------------
T1               E001
T1               E003
T1               E007
T3               E001
T3               E010
T3               E008
T3               E011
```

Employee_Details

```
---------------------------
Employee_Id    Designation
---------------------------
E001        Engineer
E002        Professor
E003        Businessman
E004        Engineer
E005        Govt. Service
E006        Unemployed
E007        Engineer
E008        Govt. Service
E009        Professor
E010        Unemployed
E011        Professor
```

I need the result by joining three tables as shown below:

```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Training_Name   Engineer    Businessman   Unemployed    Professor   Govt. Service
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Physics           2            1                                     

    Maths             1                        1           1            1
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: Are you looking to get the column names at runtime, from the values in the **Designation** column? Or hard-code them when you write the query? You very likely want the former. That can't be done in plain SQL - it requires "dynamic SQL" (which is not SQL, despite the name), which is in most cases a sign of a flawed data model. What business problem is solved by showing the "designations" as column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT Clause. Take a look into [this article](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php).